# Thermal drift in diodes

Tags: diodes, temperature, pn-junction, drift

Hi guys and thanks for reading and your help. I can't understand a thing that my book says: "When the temperature grows, the diode will let flow more current" and then it gives 2 formulas:

1. \$V_t = \frac{nKT}{Q}\$
2. \$I = I_o( e^{\frac{V}{V_t}}-1\$)

Where T is the temperature in Kelvins, K is the Boltzman constant and q is the charge of an electron. The problem is that when \$V_t\$ grows (So when the temperature grows) \$e^{V/V_t}\$ will become smaller, since a number divided by a bigger number will become smaller, and so \$I_o\$ will become smaller. If \$I_o\$ become smaller, also \$I\$ does. So when the temperature grows, \$I\$ will become smaller, but my reasoning is wrong. Why?

Comment: You should replace "temperature grow" with "temperature increases".

Comment: This effect, inside bipolar transistors (and modern foundary MOS transistors), leads to **THERMAL** runaway, destroyed transistors, broken circuits, confused engineers, and warrantee problems. Oh, and per Jet Propulsion Labs, broken spacecraft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*so Io will become smaller* That's not true, what you wanted to write is that the term \$(e^{V/V_t}-1)\$ becomes smaller and that is true.

However \$I_0\$ is often / usually (wrongly) assumed to be constant, **but it is not**.

\$I_0\$ (also called \$I_s\$) relates to the **diffusion current** which is **VERY** temperature dependent. It completely overrules the fact that \$(e^{V/V_t}-1)\$ becomes smaller.